# Extensiones/complemento Sheets

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-reporting

buenos dias.

Alguno me pude decir como hacer una conexión a Google Sheets desde Google Anlytics 3? alguna extension en particular?
Probe con diferentes extensiones pero no logro desglozar por fecha la cantidad de usuarios, siempre me los limte a 224 resgistros y viendolo desde GA3 tengo 488.

Necesito colocar en cada columna user ID (dimension2)

Gracias.

adjunto capturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si ya te funciona pero no trae los datos como los necesitas entonces puede ser el código que usas el que deberías corregir. Sea como sea, no dices en la pregunta desde qué contexto y con qué lenguaje de programación estás trabajando. Tampoco muestras el código que usas y que arroja esos datos erróneos. Por otra parte, [GA3 dejará de funcionar en julio del 2023](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528), deberías centrarte en [GA 4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10089681), activarlo si no lo has hecho y empezar a recopilar datos desde esa nueva propiedad.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No estoy usando ningun lenguaje de programacion, solo una extension de en Sheets que se llama "Google Analytics" me conecto y me levanta toda la informacion. Sigo con el problema que cuando coloco Metricas (users, session, etc) me agrupa cantidades de usuarios, no me marca de a uno por user ID.